# How to convert this formula to CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have the following formula and want to turn it into CNF without creating a truth table:

```
~((X -> ~(Y or Z)) and ((X and Y) or ~Z))
```

I was doing the following steps:

1. Remove Implication
2. Move negation inwards
3. Apply distributive laws

Then I get:

```
(((X and Y) or (X and Z)) or ((Z and ~X) or (Z and ~Y)))
```

But that is not CNF. What are the next steps to do so I will get a CNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{gather}
\neg((X \implies \neg(Y \lor Z)) \land ((X \land Y) \lor \neg Z)) \\
\neg ((\neg X \lor \neg (Y \lor Z)) \land ((X \land Y) \lor \neg Z)) \\
\neg (\neg X \lor \neg (Y \lor Z)) \lor \neg ((X \land Y) \lor \neg Z)\\
(X \land (Y \lor Z)) \lor ((\neg X \lor \neg Y) \land Z)\\
(X \lor (\neg X \lor \neg Y))
\land (X \lor Z)
\land ((Y \lor Z) \lor (\neg X \lor \neg Y))
\land ((Y \lor Z) \lor Z) \\
(X \lor \neg X \lor \neg Y)
\land (X \lor Z)
\land (Y \lor Z \lor \neg X \lor \neg Y)
\land (Y \lor Z \lor Z)&\text{already CNF}\\
1 \land (X \lor Z) \land 1 \land (Y \lor Z)\\
(X \lor Z) \land (Y \lor Z)
\end{gather}
You could stop at line 6, but the CNF can be simplified further, as shown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i don't understand what happens between line 4 and 5, can you explain me please?

Comment: It is distributing $\lor$ over $\land$: $$(A \land B) \lor (C \land D) = (A \lor C) \land (A \lor D) \land (B \lor C) \land (B \lor D)$$